# Rest endpoint with CompletableFuture vs Rest endpoint without CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, completable-future

What is the difference between getPerson endpoint in PersonController and PersonController1 in the code below?

In this specific case, what are the benefits of using CompletableFuture?

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;


    @GetMapping("/persons/{personId}" )
    public CompletableFuture<Person> getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") Integer personId) {

        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> personService.getPerson(personId));
    }
}
```

```
@RestController
public class PersonController1 {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;


    @GetMapping("/persons/{personId}" )
    public Person getPerson(@PathVariable("personId") Integer personId) {

        return personService.getPerson(personId);
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class PersonService {


    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Transactional
    public Person getPerson(int personId) {

        return personRepository.getPerson(personId);//this will get the data from the DB

    }
}
```

Comment: The one with the `CompletableFuture` can be run async. Meaning it will free the request handling thread and start a background thread to finish the processing, when finished it will get another thread to send the response. THe other one is blocking a single request handling thread the whole time.

Comment: This is mostly useful when you are using asynchronous API's (in particular I/O API's) as it avoids keeping threads waiting, thus you can do more with less threads.